# Google App Maker - Button onClick read and sum up from textbox to a label

Tags: java, button, textbox, label, google-app-maker

i´m stuck on a maybe simple function.

I have 3 widgets : One TextBox, One Label, and a Button.

What I need is :

OnClick the Button --> Reads the value of the textbox (number) and adds this amount to the current value of the Label widget.

For example :   current value of the Label = 500
                ,write in the text box 300 and click the button ,
the value of the label changes to 800.

Here are screenshot,and my not working code.

I appreciate every help.

Greetings

```
var einlesefeld =  app.currentPage.descendants.TextBox179;
var gesamtnummer = app.currentPage.descendants.Label161;

gesamtnummer.value = gesamtnummer.value + einlesefeld.value;
```

Comment: screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMXHC.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the exact same problem I had when I first started with App Maker. To understand why this is not working, I went over the [Widgets API Documentation](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/appmaker/scripting/api/widgets). Unlike the TextBox widget, the Label widget contains a **text** property and not a **value** property; Hence it is not working. Please change it to this:

```
var einlesefeld =  app.currentPage.descendants.TextBox179;
var gesamtnummer = app.currentPage.descendants.Label161;

var updatedValue = Number(gesamtnummer.text) + Number(einlesefeld.value);
gesamtnummer.text = updatedValue.toString();
```

Comment: now, the addition works in strings so when i have 15 + 20  =  1520   instead of = 35,

how do i correct this ?  when using parseInt i get Type mismatch: Cannot set type Number for property text. Type String is expected.

Comment: @robin.e I have updated the answer to suit your needs. If the answer is helpful, please consider marking it as accepted or upvote it. thanks.

Comment: i´ve tried this for 3 hours now... @Morfinismo thank you so much, for the quick awesome help. upvoted and accepted .